# Downloading distro source

Tags: linux, linux-mint, source-code

I'm using LDME, a Debian based distro.

Is there someway, preferably automatic, where one could download the source to everything that might be executed and everything needed by those executables? I'd also like the downloaded "items" to be stored under one common directory, though a hierarchical structure under that directory would be fine.

An extra requirement would be to keep track of what was downloaded ( because that source would only be the source of a snapshot) and update that tree to what is presently installed.

**NOTE:** To be clear, I want to be able to download *ALL* the source for the software that's included with my distro.

Comment: This may help for individual packages [How do I get the source code of packages installed through apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)